# Unable to change Power BI connection string using API

Tags: c#, active-directory, powerbi

I'm trying to change Power BI connection string using their API `(Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory)`. Using this API, I'm able to publish .pbix file to my PBI account. But Getting `Bad Request` error while trying to update dataset connection string. Here is my code.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

var restUrlImportPbix = POWER_BI_SERVICE_ROOT_URL + $"datasets/{dataset.id}/Default.SetAllConnections";

var postData = new { connectionString = _powerBISettings.DataConnectionString };
var response = client.PostAsync(restUrlImportPbix, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```

Also I found in a blog that *SetAllConnections only works on direct query connections*. Anybody help please.

Comment: You are probably having issues with the credentials after publishing.  I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare first request before publishing with first request that is failing and make sure all the headers match.  After publishing are you running on same machine or different machine?  I would test publish results on machine that works to verify the publish code works.  I would also check the VS bin folder and make sure all the files in the bin folder are in the same folder as the executable after publishing.

Comment: I'm using same `access token` which is used for publishing `.pbix`.

Comment: Are you saying that the error is due to using the same token from two different machines at the same time?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the reason behind it. But using same access token, I can publish .pbix, but cannot change connection string.

Comment: A PBIX file is XML which is text and can be opened with Notepad.  Check the file to see if all the references are valid after publishing.  The XML may be referencing a file in a different folder.

Comment: I can see that .pbix file is not an XML. Unable to open in Notepad or Notepad++.

Comment: I read too quickly.  The following says "OFFICE XML" : https://fileinfo.com/extension/pbix.  So you should be able to open with Word.

Comment: I'm unable to open in MS Word too. However I dont need it to open in MS Word. I just want to change Power BI connection string using API.

Comment: .pbix files are zip files. Change the extension to zip and open it. It contains multiple xml files.

Comment: Yes, I can extract it now. Inside it, there is a `Settings` file without any extension. I assume that it is containing connection string. But unable to open it.

Comment: Unzip the files and then edit the unzipped files.

Comment: I have unzipped it. There are 8 files in it. 7 of them are `application/octet-stream` type and unable to open with any application, another one is XML. Which one to edit now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to trying to redirect the datasource by changing the connection string, you can achieve the same by allowing the report itself to switch it's data source. To do this, use [connection specific parameters](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/bi/power-bi-introduction-working-with-parameters-in-power-bi-desktop-part-4/) in the report. To do this, open `Power Query Editor` by clicking `Edit Queries` and in `Manage Parameters` define two new text parameters, lets name them `ServerName` and `DatabaseName`:

[image]

[image]

Set their current values to point to one of your data sources, e.g. `SQLSERVER2016` and 'AdventureWorks2016`. Then right click your query in the report and open`Advanced Editor`. Find the server name and database name in the M code:

[image]

and replace them with the parameters defined above, so the M code will look like this:

[image]

Now you can close and apply changes and your report should work as before. But now when you want to change the data source, do it using `Edit Parameters`:

[image]

and change the server and/or database name to point to the other data source, that you want to use for your report:

[image]

After changing parameter values, Power BI Desktop will ask you to apply the changes and reload the data from the new data source. To change the parameter values (i.e. the data source) of a report published in Power BI Service, go to dataset's settings and enter new server and/or database name:

[image]

If the server is on-premise, check the `Gateway connection` too, to make sure that it is configured properly to use the right gateway. You may also want to check the available gateways in `Manage gateways`:

[image]

After changing the data source, refresh your dataset to get the data from the new data source. With Power BI Pro account you can do this 8 times per 24 hours, while if the dataset is in a dedicated capacity, this limit is raised to 48 times per 24 hours.

To do this programatically, use [`Update Parameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updateparameters) / [`Update Parameters In Group`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/updateparametersingroup) and [`Refresh Dataset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdataset) / [`Refresh Dataset In Group`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdatasetingroup) REST API calls, or if I modify your code, something like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

var restUrlUpdateParameters = POWER_BI_SERVICE_ROOT_URL + $"datasets/{dataset.id}/Default.UpdateParameters";
var postData = new { updateDetails = new[] { new { name = "ServerName", newValue = "NEWSERVER" }, new { name = "DatabaseName", newValue = "Another_AdventureWorks2016" } } };
var responseUpdate = client.PostAsync(restUrlUpdateParameters, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

var restUrlRefreshDataset = POWER_BI_SERVICE_ROOT_URL + $"datasets/{dataset.id}/refreshes";
var responseRefresh = client.PostAsync(restUrlRefreshDataset, null).Result;
```

This is a easy way to make your reports "switchable", e.g. for switching one report from DEV or QA to PROD environment, or as part of your disaster recovery plan, to automate switching all reports in some workgroup to another DR server. In general I recommend to define such connection specific parameters in all reports.

Comment: I already got this solution in between days. But still not able to change data source username and password. Any solution for these?

Comment: You are entering the credentials for a data source when you are installing and configuring the gateway to it. So it should use them.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But I'm trying to use the same pbix file for different accounts. I don't want to change them so many times using power bi desktop.

Comment: I do not understand, Neither datasource credentials are kept in the pbix file, nor the gateway configuration and credentials used. So you can publish the **same** pbix file as many times as you want and point each one to a different data source (or different account, if I use your words). What do you mean by "change them so many times"?

Comment: oh ok, I understand.